# SQL WHERE statement syntax error when using distinct count left

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `WHERE` clause that logically I want it to bring back results where the first digit of the  short names don't match.

The short names can be:

```
1.1
1.2
2.1
2.2
```

Sample data WITHOUT `where` clause:

```
+-----------+--------+------+
| Shortname | number |  ID  |
+-----------+--------+------+
| 2.1       |      1 | 3333 |
| 1.1       |     60 | 3333 |
| 1.2       |     90 | 3333 |
| 2.1       |     50 | 4444 |
| 2.2       |     30 | 4444 |
| 1.1       |     80 | 5555 |
| 1.2       |     10 | 5555 |
+-----------+--------+------+
```

Expected data WITH `where` clause:

```
+-----------+--------+------+
| Shortname | number |  ID  |
+-----------+--------+------+
| 2.1       |      1 | 3333 |
| 1.1       |     60 | 3333 |
| 1.2       |     90 | 3333 |
+-----------+--------+------+
```

I tried the code:

```
SELECT shortname, number, id
FROM table
WHERE ((left(shortname,1) like '%1%') != ((left(shortname,1) like '%2%')
```

But it generates the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near '!'.

**Clarification UPDATE**

I need the results per ID, so in the sample above there are ID's 3333, 4444 and 5555.  I want to only bring back the ID `3333` because it doesn't have only a single first character value in each `shortname`. It contains both values `1` and `2`.

Where as I don't want to see the other ID's as there short names are matching on the first digit 1 = 1 and 2 = 2 etc.

Comment: Use <>  instead of !=

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: `left(shortname,1) like '%1%'` doesn't make sense. `left(..,1)` will return a single character anyway, so there is no need for a `like` with wildcards. This can be replaced with: left(shortname,1) = '1'`. But I don't really understand what you are trying to retrieve. Why isn't `shortname = 2.2` not included in the expected output?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the results should be per ID, so if an ID has the short names 1.1 and 1.2 i or if it had 2.1 and 2.2 i dont want to see them, BUT if an ID has mixed short names 1.1 and 2.1 for example i want to see them

Comment: I don't understand. Don't match with what? For example, what's the difference with the first and the fourth record? Why you see the first and not the fourth?

Comment: Updated question to clarify

Comment: I dont undertand what you want, you are comparing two conditions so you will always get an error

Comment: This way you wouldn't see the ID 3333 too becauase it has a shortname 1.1.

Comment: @fly_ua nope, that's not the problem - [that is mostly a personal preference](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2008/03/20/which-to-use-or.aspx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to return the `ID` that a multiple first characters in the `shortname`, then first look at getting a distinct count of the rows:

```
select id
from yourtable
group by id
having count(distinct left(shortname, 1)) > 1;
```

This should return to you the rows that have both a 2 and a 1 as the first character when associated with the IDs.  Then you can use this to return the rest of the data:

```
;with cte as
(
  select id
  from yourtable
  group by id
  having count(distinct left(shortname, 1)) > 1
)
select 
  t.shortname,
  t.number, 
  t.id
from yourtable t
inner join cte c
  on t.id = c.id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d75723/1). This returns:

```
| SHORTNAME | NUMBER |   ID |
|-----------|--------|------|
|       2.1 |      1 | 3333 |
|       1.1 |     60 | 3333 |
|       1.2 |     90 | 3333 |
```

A more flexible option would be to get the characters before the decimal and verify that you have a distinct count of all the digits.  To do this, you'll use a function like [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) along with the `LEFT`.

```
;with cte as
(
  select id
  from yourtable
  group by id
  having count(distinct left(shortname, charindex('.', shortname)-1)) > 1
)
select 
  t.shortname,
  t.number, 
  t.id
from yourtable t
inner join cte c
  on t.id = c.id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/907356/2). This will return:

```
| SHORTNAME | NUMBER |   ID |
|-----------|--------|------|
|       2.1 |      1 | 3333 |
|       1.1 |     60 | 3333 |
|       1.2 |     90 | 3333 |
|      14.1 |      5 | 6666 |
|      14.2 |     78 | 6666 |
|      24.1 |     89 | 6666 |
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing two conditions! You might want to do something like this:

```
SELECT shortname, number, id
FROM table
WHERE ((left(shortname,1) like '%1%') OR ((left(shortname,1) like '%2%')))
```

Anyway for you problem:

```
SELECT shortname, number, id
FROM (
SELECT shortname, number, id, (SELECT COUNT(*)
                               FROM table AS TI
                               WHERE LEFT(ShortName, 1) = RIGHT(ShortName, 1)
                                 AND TI.ID = T.ID) AS C
FROM table AS T) AS TT
```

WHERE C = 0

But this leave out the ID 3333 too because it has one shortname = 1.1.

Comment: On the right track but that brings back everything still

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: see sample in question

Answer (score 2):

How about:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86276/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Sample
(
  Shortname VARCHAR(10),
  number tinyint,
  Id int)

INSERT INTO Sample
VALUES
   ('2.1', 1, 3333),
   ('1.1', 60, 3333),
   ('1.2', 90, 3333),
   ('2.1', 50, 4444),
   ('2.2', 30, 4444),
   ('1.1', 80, 5555),
   ('1.2', 10, 5555)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT shortname, number, id
FROM [Sample] t1
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM [Sample] t2 
   WHERE t1.id = t2.id and LEFT(t1.shortname,1) <> LEFT(t2.shortname,1))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86276/1/0)**:

```
| SHORTNAME | NUMBER |   ID |
|-----------|--------|------|
|       2.1 |      1 | 3333 |
|       1.1 |     60 | 3333 |
|       1.2 |     90 | 3333 |
```

Answer (score -2):

Please check you `select` query

It should be Like this

```
SELECT shortname, number, id
FROM table
WHERE ((left(shortname,1) like '%1%') <> ((left(shortname,1) like '%2%')))
```

You missed to **close** the **))** brackets.